# Making concurrent call in Bluebird promise using Sequelize findOne method . Returns undefined

Tags: promise, sequelize.js, bluebird

I want to verify existence of specific user data from multiple tables to make it a concurrent call i am using Bluebird Promise.Prop like given below. Data is acceded Using sequelize ORM.

```
Promise.props({
  user: (()=>{
    return User.findOne({
        where: {username: req.user.username}

    });
  }),
  comments: (()=>{
    return comments.findOne({
        where: {username: req.user.username}

    });
  })
}).then((result)=> {
    console.log(result.user.name, result.comments.count);
});
```

I also tried with a nested promise but doesn't succeeded. like

```
 Promise.props({
   user: (()=>{
    return User.findOne({
        where: {username: req.user.username}

    }).then((user)=>{
      console.log(user.name); // even here i am getting undefined
    });
  }),
  comments: (()=>{
    return comments.findOne({
        where: {username: req.user.username}

    });
  })
}).then((result)=> {
    console.log(result.user.name, result.comments.count);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clear if `result.user` is undefined, or `result.user.name` is undefined.
I expect the latter.

You pass an object with 2 keys to Promise.props.
But both of the keys are a function, and not a promise. So promise.props sees the function, not the promise.
The result should still have the 2 functions.

Try

```
Promise.props({
  user: User.findOne({
        where: {username: req.user.username}
  }),
  comments: comments.findOne({
        where: {username: req.user.username}
  })
}).then((result)=> {
    console.log(result.user.name, result.comments.count);
});
```

Other good ways are Promise.all, or if you know how many promises you have then use Promise.join

```
Promise.join(
  User.findOne({
        where: {username: req.user.username}
  }),
  comments.findOne({
        where: {username: req.user.username}
  }),
  (user, comment) => {
    console.log(user.name, comments.count);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the `Promise` itself rather than the resolve value. The results need to be collected in the promise resolution and an then be passed along.

```js
// collect values in this object
const values = {};
// run all promises
Promise.all([
  model.findOne()
  .then((val) => {
    // assign result 1
    values.val1 = val;
    return Promise.resolve();
  }),
  model.findOne()
  .then((val) => {
    // assign result 2
    values.val2 = val;
    return Promise.resolve();
  }),
])
.then(() => {
  // the values will be collected here.
  console.log(values);
});
```